# Android Xamarin - Closed app notification

Tags: c#, android, .net, xamarin, notifications

I'd like to create notificiation in my app, which is going to be showed in 10 seconds. It works well, when application is running, but when I close the application, notification is not showed. Here is my code:

My notification service:

```
[Service]
class NotifyEvent : IntentService
{
    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
        builder.SetContentTitle(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.NotifikaceNadpis));
        builder.SetContentText(Resources.GetString(Resource.String.NotifikaceText));
        builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        builder.SetPriority(1);
        builder.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);
        builder.SetWhen(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis());
        Notification notifikace = builder.Build();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;

        const int notificationId = 0;
        notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notifikace);
    }
}
```

Class, which starts notification:

```
public class Notificator
{
    public void ShowNotification(Context context)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(NotifyEvent));
        var pendingServiceIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);

        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

        alarm.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtimeWakeup, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 10000, pendingServiceIntent);
    }
}
```

Method in activity:

```
Notificator not = new Notificator();
not.ShowNotification(this);
```

My Activity:

```
[Activity(Label = "Nastavení")]
public class SettingsActivity : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your application here
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Settings);
        Button vynulovatButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buttonRestartDne);

        vynulovatButton.Click += VynulovatDen;

    }

    ...

    protected void VynulovatDen(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Notificator not = new Notificator();
        not.ShowNotification(this);
    }
}
```

Thanks for every help.

Comment: add codefor activity.

Comment: code for activity has been aded

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
       Notificator not = new Notificator();
        not.ShowNotification(this);  
            base.OnDestroy();
        }
```

Comment: It didn't help.

Comment: have you added this in your activity

Comment: yes, but it works same as before... when i close the app in 10 seconds, no notification is fired.

Comment: then you need to have broadcast for this.

Comment: I have tried broadcast before and it didn't work too.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep your service alive when you destroy your application.

1. add `return StartCommandResult.Sticky;` in the `OnStartCommand` method.
2. start the service `OnTaskRemoved`  function.

Create your service with the `Service` interface, the `IntentService` is for Time-consuming operation.

```
 class NotifyEvent : Service
    {
        [return: GeneratedEnum]
        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, [GeneratedEnum] StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {
            new Task(() => {

                PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
                Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this);
                builder.SetContentTitle("hello");
                builder.SetContentText("hello");
                builder.SetSmallIcon(Resource.Drawable.Icon);
                builder.SetPriority(1);
                builder.SetDefaults(NotificationDefaults.Sound | NotificationDefaults.Vibrate);
                builder.SetWhen(Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis());
                Notification notifikace = builder.Build();
                NotificationManager notificationManager = GetSystemService(Context.NotificationService) as NotificationManager;
                const int notificationId = 0;
                notificationManager.Notify(notificationId, notifikace);

            }).Start();
            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            return null;
        }
        public override void OnTaskRemoved(Intent rootIntent)
        {
            Intent restartService = new Intent(ApplicationContext, typeof(NotifyEvent));
            restartService.SetPackage(PackageName);
            var pendingServiceIntent = PendingIntent.GetService(ApplicationContext, 0, restartService, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
            AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)ApplicationContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            alarm.Set(AlarmType.ElapsedRealtime, SystemClock.ElapsedRealtime() + 1000, pendingServiceIntent);

            System.Console.WriteLine("service OnTaskRemoved");
            base.OnTaskRemoved(rootIntent);
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I have Huawei phone. Is this working when I don't move my app to Protected apps manually?

Comment: @MikBig You can try it on Huawei phone, I do not have Huawei phone device. I think it works.