# How can I update my widget in xamarin when app is killed?

Tags: android, xamarin, service, widget, alarmmanager

I have widget which extends AppWidgetProvider. There is a button, by clicking on it, updates widget screen with a new data. When I kill my parent app, widget doesn't succeed to bring a new data. As I understood I need to write service or alarm manager in order to keep my app running in background. Where should I implement this in code? How can I do it in xamarin?
My code is:

```
    [BroadcastReceiver(Label = "@string/widget_name")]
    [IntentFilter(new string[] { "android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" })]
    [MetaData("android.appwidget.provider", Resource = "@xml/widget_word")]
    public class WidgetProvider : AppWidgetProvider
    {
        public static string UPDATE_LIST = "UPDATE_LIST";
        public override void OnUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
        {
            base.OnUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

            ComponentName thiswidget = new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(WidgetProvider)).Name);
            int[] allWidgetsIds = appWidgetManager.GetAppWidgetIds(thiswidget);

            for (int i = 0; i < allWidgetsIds.Length; i++)
            {

                RemoteViews remoteViews = new RemoteViews(context.PackageName, Resource.Layout.widget_layout);
                Intent svcIntent = new Intent(context, typeof(WidgetService));
                svcIntent.SetPackage(context.PackageName);
                svcIntent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetId, allWidgetsIds[i]);
                remoteViews.SetRemoteAdapter(Resource.Id.listViewWidget, svcIntent);


                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(WidgetProvider));
                intent.SetAction(AppWidgetManager.ActionAppwidgetUpdate);
                intent.PutExtra(AppWidgetManager.ExtraAppwidgetIds, appWidgetIds[i]);


                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
                remoteViews.SetOnClickPendingIntent(Resource.Id.btnupdate, pi);

                appWidgetManager.UpdateAppWidget(allWidgetsIds[i], remoteViews);
            }
        }

        public override void OnReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
        {
            base.OnReceive(context, intent);
            if (intent.Action.Equals(AppWidgetManager.ActionAppwidgetUpdate))
            {
                updateWidget(context);                
            }
        }
        private void updateWidget(Context context)
        {
            AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.GetInstance(context);
            int[] appWidgetids = appWidgetManager.GetAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(WidgetProvider)).Name));
            appWidgetManager.NotifyAppWidgetViewDataChanged(appWidgetids, Resource.Id.listViewWidget);
        }
    }
```

Comment: follow my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41652560/android-xamarin-closed-app-notification/41670814#41670814) to keep your service alive. And update your widget.

Comment: When I kill my app, can I still use its functions in order to get data or it unreachable? Can I wake up back my app?

Comment: The data `allWidgetsIds[i]` is store in the memory. When you kill the app the memory data for the app is cleared. If you store the data in the file or sqlite. I think you can get the data.